# What does "$L$ seconds" mean in $\lambda = 0.225L \ \rm s$?

Tags: kinematics, terminology, definition

I was reading a paper, (Iannou et Chien 1993) and they were trying to determine the exact amount of reaction time on the California safety spacing rule, and the result was:

$ \lambda = 0.225 L\ \rm s$

And I am confused as to where did that $L$ come from, and what it's meaning is supposed to be.
The logic is that the continuous spacing rule (distance between vehicles) is given by :

$S_i = v_i.\lambda + \lambda_2$

Where $S_i$ is the safety distance from the preceding vehicle, $v_i$ is the velocity of the vehicle and $\lambda$s are integration constants where $\lambda_2$ is the spacing limit, and $\lambda$ is the reaction time.

And the California rule dictates that for every 10 miles per hour, an additional distance of about 4.5 meters from the previous vehicle should given.

Is $L$ supposed to mean some kind of Integer division here?

(Iannou et Chien 1993): P. A. Ioannou and C. C. Chien, "Autonomous intelligent cruise control," in IEEE Transactions on Vehicular Technology, vol. 42, no. 4, pp. 657-672, Nov. 1993, doi: 10.1109/25.260745.

Comment: $L$ is the vehicle length in meters—see the bottom right of p660. (Thus, the coefficient of 0.225 has units of seconds per meter.) It's in the same sentence as the relation you quote. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting your question?

Comment: oh... I kept going back even farther and reproducing. I really missed it ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

On p.660, the authors define $L$ as "one vehicle length," and suggest 15ft ≈ 4.5m as a typical value.

As a rule, it is more useful in mathematical modeling to define scale parameters in terms of things in your model versus arbitrary standards.  Imagine driving down the highway with a teenage student driver who is following too closely.  You would be much more likely to say, "you want three or four car lengths between you and the car in front" versus "aim for a gap of at least 13.5 meters."

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's a paper I read long ago and wanted to reproduce. I really missed that line out! sorry. the reaction time roughly translates to around 1 second (the real reaction time observed is more than 1.5 seconds). Here it's like saying give a quarter of your car's length in time to get your reaction time, and as you said it keeps the model close to an intelligible rule of thumb.